# Python not finding google module

Tags: python

I'm using `python 3.9.1` and I'm trying to use the google api in my script.

When I run the script it complains that it can't find the google module:

```
    python .\gcp_list_buckets.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\bluet\OneDrive\Desktop\important_folders\project\git\cloud_scripts\gcp_scripts\python\gcp_list_buckets.py", line 1, in <module>
        from google.cloud import storage
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'
```

I'm working in a `virtual env` and I installed the `google` module before running it:

```sh
$ pip show google
Name: google
Version: 3.0.0
Summary: Python bindings to the Google search engine.
Home-page: http://breakingcode.wordpress.com/
Author: Mario Vilas
Author-email: mvilas@gmail.com
License: UNKNOWN
Location: c:\users\bluet\onedrive\desktop\important_folders\project\git\cloud_scripts\gcp_scripts\python\venv\lib\site-packages
Requires: beautifulsoup4
Required-by:
```

This is my import statement in my script:

```
from google.cloud import storage
```

Why am I getting this error and how do I get past this?

Comment: I don't think you have the [package](https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage) installed. Installing the module google doesnt bring in absolutely everything available. The package you have installed isn't even an official google package. Try `pip install google-cloud-storage`. Then run it again.

Comment: Thanks that did it. If you put that as the answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have the right package installed. You need the `google-cloud-storage` package.

```
pip install google-cloud-storage
```